# Does the Playstation Move 'Wand' work with the PS4 camera?

Tags: ps4, playstation-move

I've read that [Playstation 4 supports PS3 Move controllers](http://venturebeat.com/2013/02/22/good-news-move-controllers-work-on-playstation-4-bad-news-dualshock-3-doesnt/).  But what does this actually mean?

- Does the [PS3 camera](http://us.playstation.com/ps3/accessories/playstation-eye-camera-ps3.html) *(aka PS eye, aka PS Move camera)* work with PS4?
- If I own the [PS4 camera](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BGAA3S2) but not the PS3 camera, will I still be able to use the [Playstation Move wands](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I0J51U)?
- Do all PS4 Camera games also work with Playstation Move wands, or only some?  If it's only some, how do I know which ones?
- If a PS4 Camera game *(like Just Dance 2015)* works both with and without the wand, will having the wand improve the experience *(eg. more accurate tracking)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [The Playstation 3 (PS3) move controllers work with Playstation 4 (PS4), the Playstation "Eye" (ps3) dont](http://attackofthefanboy.com/news/playstation-move-compatible-ps4/):

> The latest set of tweets reveal that the PlayStation Move and Navigation controllers will work with the PS4, but the PlayStation Eye won’t.

2. PS 4 supports the Move Wands [(Same source)](http://attackofthefanboy.com/news/playstation-move-compatible-ps4/).
3. As the PS4 has PS3 Move full support, every game should work with ps3 wands because the games just use an interface of the PS4 to get the collected move data so they dont know if it's a PS3 or PS4 Move you're using.
4. I can't give you an answer to the last point because i dont like using Move for games so I've no experience here.

[Additional information on the Playstation website.](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5229/~/ps4%3A-ps-move-controller-information)

And i found one more interesting post on [this reddit:](http://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/1grpfv/sops4_is_move_compatiblewill_the_current_camera/)

> The move camera is 640x480 at 60fps. In other words, it has what is effectively the same quality camera that is in the PS Vita (not a good camera at all), but in a much larger and more cumbersome package. The PS4 camera is two cameras at 1280x800 at 60fps.

Comment: What does _"so they dont know if it's a PS3 or PS4 Move you're using"_ mean? There is no "PS4 Move"

Answer (score 1):

> - Does the PS3 camera (aka PS eye, aka PS Move camera) work with PS4?

No.

> - If I own the PS4 camera but not the PS3 camera, will I still be able to use the Playstation Move wands?

Yes.

Some games have a 'PlayStation Move Compatible' logo on the back of the box, where it shows the game requirements. I don't know if all games that support the PlayStation Camera also support Move controllers, but you can look for that logo to know if it's supported.

Just Dance 2015 says 'PlayStation Camera compatible' and 'PlayStation Move compatible'

Answer (score 0):

I just got my PSVR today and ordered a couple PS3 controllers - I read they worked like the 4 move controllers so I figured why not save $70. I attempted to play Batman and the PS3 controllers did not work like they should for VR. The controller did connect via bluetooth but they did not act as Batman's hands or assist with the VR game in any way shape or form. I have 2 and neither one worked so I would say it will connect to the system but for VR they did not work for me.

Comment: I bought move controllers intended for PS3 and they work just fine with my PS VR.